# Can old versions of DriveItems be deleted via the Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm finding that some of my Drive Items have tons of versions and I'd like to clean some of them up.

Is it possible to do this via the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Graph API looks like it only supports list versions, get versions, get contents and restore versions for Versions of a drive item.

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitemversion?view=graph-rest-1.0

[image]

Comment: Not sure why that page eluded me.  Where's the button for "that's not the answer I wanted"?  Thank you

Comment: @coach_rob  Seems like good candidate for adding to our UserVoice https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359590

Answer (score 1):

It's still not officially listed in the documentation, but

```
DELETE /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/versions/{version-id}
```

Seems to work.